# Want to create Outlook add-in Setup for all outlook version ( i.e. outlook 2007 , outlook 2010, outlook 2013 ) etc

Tags: asp.net, outlook, outlook-addin

I have already created outlook add-in setup for outlook 2007 and outlook 2010 version.but now i face issue that it is not working on outlook 2013 and later version so i want to develop one setup which work on all outlook version.

I google lot for all in one outlook setup but i didnt find any option.

Answer (score 0):

> it is not working on outlook 2013 and later version

Do you see the add-in listed in Outlook?

There are plenty reasons why the add-in is not working...

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [Troubleshooting Run Time Errors in Office Solutions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6s0wczt9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Troubleshooting COM Add-In load failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx)
- [Troubleshooting Office Solution Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608594.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

P.S. By default, if an VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom Ribbon does not appear, or why a Ribbon appears but no controls appear. See [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.